# Mapping variables in the model to theory documentation in WRSM-Pitman

Tags: hydrology, models

I’m working with the comprehensive wetland module in WRSM-Pitman. However, the variables listed in the wetland tab of the channel module are not referred to in the same way as the variables listed in theory documentation. I am attaching a screenshot of the key parameters in the wetland tab. Please can someone confirm what they are in the theory documentation? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I’ll list them as model definitions to theory documentation variables:

Area of wetland at bankfull level of channel: Anom

Volume of wetland at bankfull level: Snom

Power of area-volume relationship: b

Bankfull capacity of river channel: Qbf (in wetland inflow equation)

Proportion of flow in excess of bankfull into wetland: Kin

Proportion of wetland vol. (over bankfull) into channel: Kout